# Why does controller gives: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, unit-test, pagereference, method

I have an apexclass with a pagereference for which I am writing a unittest but this returns an NullPointerException on `controller.toCareerPageWithFilters();` what am i missing?

```
   public class careerdetails {

        public Career__c obj{get;set;}
        public String lang { get;set; }
        PageReference retURL;

    public careerdetails(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    System.debug('careerdetails constructor');

    obj = (Career__c)stdController.getRecord();

    if (obj == null) {    
        string careerId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('careerId');
        if(String.isNotBlank(careerId)){
            obj = [SELECT Jobposition__c, JobPosting__c, Job__c, Function__c,    
                   Country__c, Area__c FROM Career__c WHERE Id = :careerId LIMIT 1];
        }
    }
}
 ..
        public PageReference toCareerPageWithFilters() {
            if(lang !='_nl'){ 
            PageReference retURL = new PageReference('https://' + URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost() + '/applycareers');
            }
            if(lang =='_nl'){ 
            PageReference retURL = new PageReference('https://' + URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost() + '/applycareers_nl');
            }
            retURL.getParameters().put('function', removeWhitespace(obj.Function__c));
            retURL.getParameters().put('country', removeWhitespace(obj.Country__c));
            retURL.getParameters().put('area', removeWhitespace(obj.Area__c));
            retURL.getParameters().put('job', removeWhitespace(obj.id));

            System.debug('retURL: ' + retURL);

            return retURL;
        }
    }
```

Unittest

```
@isTest 
private class careerdetailsTest {
    @isTest
    private static void testCareerDetails() {
        Career__c car = new Career__c();
        car.Function__c = 'Function 1';
        car.Country__c = 'NL';
        car.Area__c = 'Area 1';
        insert car; 

        PageReference pageRef = Page.careerdetails;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('careerId','' + car.Id);
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(car);
        careerdetails controller = new careerdetails(sc);
        controller.toCareerPageWithFilters();
        System.assertNotEquals(null,pageRef);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your careerdetails class's constructor set "obj" by getting the standard controller's related record? You didn't include the constructor details...

Comment: @PhilW I added the constructor details.

Comment: Where does the log say you tried to deference a null object? Can you include the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your test, careerdetails.obj is not set the way you intended.

The Id string careerId is empty, as your test class does not set the URL-parameter. Your way of filling obj can be optimized - that is, if I understand your objective correctly.

In

```
obj = (Career__c)stdController.getRecord();
```

you get the record that is correctly set from your test class. But then you throw that away to query based on `careerId`:

```
string careerId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('careerId');
obj = new Career__c();

if(String.isNotBlank(careerId)){
    obj = [SELECT Jobposition__c, JobPosting__c, Job__c, Function__c, Country__c, Area__c FROM Career__c WHERE Id = :careerId LIMIT 1];
}
```

If you need to react to the parameter `careerId`, change your test class to set the parameter:

```
pageRef.getParameters().put('careerId','' + car.Id);
```

Better yet, update your controller to react to both:

```
if (obj == null) {    
    string careerId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('careerId');
    if(String.isNotBlank(careerId)){
        obj = [SELECT Jobposition__c, JobPosting__c, Job__c, Function__c,    
               Country__c, Area__c FROM Career__c WHERE Id = :careerId LIMIT 1];
    }
}
```

The NullPointer will in all likelihood happen in `removeWhitespace()`. Anyway, without the parameter obj.Function__c is null.

Comment: I added your suggestions (see update) but still get the nullpointer exception.

Comment: In that case I have to second @ZachHutchins: can you provide the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working off @Florian_Heer's answer which I do believe is a decent answer then I do still see several issues however. One a failure to mention that in order for *getRecord()* to work properly you need to reference the fields on the visualforce page. Strait from the documentation on *getRecord()*. Which means its not exactly as one to one replacement to doing a soql query, they can be different field sets.

> "Note that only the fields that are referenced in the associated
>   Visualforce markup are available for querying on this SObject. All
>   other fields, including fields from any related objects, must be
>   queried using a SOQL expression."

Also I am not sure why you are using Id here for this line when you have a field called job

```
retURL.getParameters().put('job', removeWhitespace(obj.id));
```

In your test you are adding the career object to the standard controller so I'm guessing you are taking the *getRecord()* path over the secondary path of get *careerId*. Furthermore as mentioned in another answer it most likely is *removeWhitespace()* that is throwing the exception as you are trimming or trying to call a method on null reference. Make sure the fields are on the visualforce page either visible or invisible https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_getRecord.htm tells you this. Make sure you are checking for null in the *removeWhitespace()* method I'm sure its legitimate to have a null field on your object you should handle this situation somehow.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I always run into the issue with the missing fields... :-)